# Mailchimp webhook - manually subscribing and unsubscribing

Tags: mailchimp, webhooks, mailchimp-api-v3.0

My webhook is working fine. During testing, when I manually unsubscribe a user, the webhook fires. However, when I manually resubscribe that same user, nothing happens. I've tested this; manual unsubscribes fire, manual subscribes do not. What's going on here? Why doesn't Mailchimp send an event to my webhook for manual subscribes?

Edit: this is the strangest bug. If you manually click Subscribe from the members's profile, nothing happens, but if you tick the member's name from the list and click Resubscribe, the webhook fires. Mailchimp, please fix this.

Comment: Are you using the API? Which method? `CURL`?

Comment: @scoopzilla I've built a webhook which receives data from Mailchimp (ASP.NET MVC stack). It's just another stupid Mailchimp bug. When you manually click "Subscribe" from the member's profile (after manually unsubscribing), nothing is sent to the webhook. But if you go to the list view, tick next to the member's name, and click "Resubscribe" (under actions), it works. Manual unsubscribes fire in both cases. Yet another stupid, time-wasting Mailchimp bug.

Comment: Got stuck on the same problem today. Have you reported this to mailchimp?

Comment: @Paul Yes, I asked them to look at this question. Seems they haven't done anything about it. I've had lots of stupid little issues like this. I expected integration with Mailchimp to be easy. It turned out to be the hardest, most unfriendly integration I've ever done. So many wtfs. Never again. The killer for me is that retries only happen for 75 mins. No room for downtime, could mess up my system as data gets out of sync. Perhaps you could ask them to fix it.

Comment: I did ask them. Thanks for letting me know, I guess I'll go with a daily job to patch inconsistent data. Totally agree with wtfs, their docs... Work with Stripe was way more straight-forward, despite payments should actually be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

When a user unsubscribes, because of potential spam complaints, Mailchimp doesn't allow you to add the user to your list again. You have to send a request, and they'll have to accept the requests themselves for them to be subscribed again.